# Bootstrap Modal setting id using jquery not working

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I'm creating some modals as follow:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary student" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id={{item.st_number}}>
  Open modal
</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal body -->
      <div class="modal-body">
        Modal body..
      </div>

      <!-- Modal footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to change modal ids to button data-id field with the following script:

```
    $(document).on("click", ".student", function() {
        var stid = $(this).data('id');
        $(".modal-header h5").html(stid);
        $(this).find('.myModal').text(stid);
    });
```

changing modal header works, but modal name is not changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `find()` like that because `.find()` method allows us to search through the descendants of these elements in the DOM tree .  Use `next()` with `find()` to get element and change text.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".student", function() {
  var stid = $(this).data('id');
  $(this).next('div').find(".modal-header h4").text(stid);
  $(this).next('div.modal').attr('id', stid);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary student" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id={{item.st_number}}>
  Open modal
</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal body -->
      <div class="modal-body">
        Modal body..
      </div>

      <!-- Modal footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your response, but when page loads, modal id is still unchanged.

Comment: If you want this on page load , you have to get id on page load ( inside `document.ready` ) not in button click,

Comment: I also checked that when I click the button, but still not change modal id

Comment: See above answer carefully. I use `append ` instead of  `text`.  Any console error ?

Comment: Dear @Shree will your code change id="myModal" to id={{item.st_number}} ?

Comment: For that you have to change ID attribute . See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

your jQuery is wrong. there are not any `h5` tag in HTML within `.modal-header` class.

you can try this

```
$(document).on("click", ".student", function() {
        var stid = $(this).data('id');
        $(".modal-header h4").text(stid);
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but the question is about how to change modal id.

Answer (score 0):

The below script xhanges you modal ID as well, try it:

```
$(document).on("click", ".student", function() {
    var stid = $(this).data('id');
    $(".modal-header h4").html(stid);
    $('.modal').attr('id', 'desired_id');
});
```